# While loop come over two times

Tags: c

My code looks like this, I couldn't handle to solve it. It has to be one time

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char x ;

    printf("enter.\n");
    scanf("%c",&x);
    while(x!='D' && x!='d')
    {
        printf("diomond.\n");
        scanf("%c",&x);
    }
}
```

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. Please edit your post with a *clear* and *concise* description of the problem you are encountering.

Comment: Sure :`int main(int argc, char* argv[])` You're welcome

Comment: Your code does not compile. You haven't asked an actual question. Your indentation makes the code hard to read. Please fix those points if you want to get answers.

Comment: http://www.c-faq.com/stdio/scanfc.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this line

```
scanf("%c",&x);
```

to

```
scanf(" %c",&x); /* Notice the space in the format specifier */
```

The reason for running twice is that when you input a character, there's a newline left in the input stream which is consumed in the next iteration. Using a leading space in the format string will be tell scanf() to ignore whitespaces.

Answer (score 1):

Use an space before `%c` specifier. This will help to eat up newline character `\n` which is left behind for the next `scanf` read, after pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> .

```
scanf(" %c",&x);  
  //   ^space

while(x!= 'D'&& x!='d')
{
   printf("diomond.\n");
   scanf(" %c",&x);
     //   ^space
}
```